# Why is variable being calculated twice in an async promise?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, async-await, promise, amazon-textract

**CURRENTLY**

I have the following function IN AWS that utilise Textract SDK async functions:

```js
async function textParse(config) {
  const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
  let textract = new AWS.Textract();

  let analysisResults;
  console.log("Before Try");
  try {
    console.log("Start Document Analysis");
    analysisResults = await textract
      .startDocumentAnalysis(config, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("There was an error during doc analysis...");
          console.log(err, err.stack);
        } // an error occurred
        else {
          console.log("Doc analysis successful!");
          console.log(data);
          return data;
        } // successful response
      })
      .promise();
  } catch (e) {
    throw "Doc Analysis Error!" + e;
  }
  let JobId = analysisResults["JobId"];
  let textractResult = await textract
    .getDocumentAnalysis({ JobId: JobId })
    .promise();

  console.log("End!")

  return textractResult;
}
```

**ISSUE**

The console log is showing that `analysisResults` is being calculated twice. Note `Doc analysis successful!` appearing twice in the logs.

```
INFO Before Try
INFO Start Document Analysis
INFO Doc analysis successful!
INFO { JobId: '3a1e00c9b5ca9123124hhfdfdsdd02f2053c38ec5249e822c9e95f' }
INFO Doc analysis successful!
INFO { JobId: '5ef298d3a9123124hhfdfdsddsdssdsdsdds689580642a6346' }
INFO End!
```

I've spent a few hours trying to debug this and I suspect it's something to do with how I'm handling promises.

Any ideas on what changes I need to make?

Comment: nothing to do with any "async promise" (or *Promise*, since promises are asynchronous by their very nature, and the only thing you can *await*, so async is redundant) - it's the callback to `startDocumentAnalysis` that is being called more than once - I think if you remove that callback and the one for `getDocumentAnalysis` you'll find the code still works

Comment: It's not - you have two console.log's from `startDocumentAnalysis` and one from `getDocumentAnalysis` - oops, replying to a deleted comment

Comment: @JaromandaX I deleted my comment because even upon removing the callback from `getDocumentAnalysis`, the "Doc analysis successful!" message is appearing twice.
`let textractResult = await textract.getDocumentAnalysis({ JobId: JobId }).promise()`

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `textParse` only once? Please add another `console` log at the top of the function. If you are, the problem would appear to be within `textract.startDocumentAnalysis`.

Comment: how can `"Doc analysis successful!"` appear at all if you removed the code that outputs `"Doc analysis successful!"` ? I think you perhaps *did something wrong™* - oh, I see, you didn't remove **BOTH** callbacks

Comment: @Bergi added some extra logs. Note, when I remove `textract.startDocumentAnalysis` the "Doc analysis successful!" log only appears once.

Comment: I'm wondering why the code passes a callback function to startDocumentAnalysis *and* awaits a promise returned by .promise. Ordinarily, you'd do one or the other.

Comment: @danh, as I wrote "I suspect it's something to do with how I'm handling promises.", I would be open to suggestions for rewriting the promise handling part of the code if you think this is the issue.

Comment: @JaromandaX Both callbacks?

Comment: @Wronski "*when I remove `textract.startDocumentAnalysis` the "Doc analysis successful!" log only appears once*" - if you remove that part of your code, where are you still logging it?

Comment: @Bergi ... look at the ORIGINAL code ... both `startDocumentAnalysis` and `getDocumentAnalysis` used a callback - I'm not an idiot!

Comment: @JaromandaX You mean the code from [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73430660/1)?

Comment: @JaromandaX, you are correct. After removing *both* callbacks, the script works fine, and only logs once! I feel a bit stupid, because I'm not entirely sure I understand why this happens, but I believe it's to do with promises and callbacks which I have yet to learn. Thank you.

Comment: Yes @bergi - he removed the callback from one of those functions after I suggested it - that's why I said he needed to remove it from BOTH. In fact, in reality, he removed the callback from the function that WASN'T outputting the message he's so worried about, then wondered why the same message is output ... you can lead a horse to water

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know the textract library, but this is what the OP code appears to be trying to say in a singular (promise, not callback) style.

```
async function textParse(config) {
  const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
  let textract = new AWS.Textract();
  console.log("Before Try");
  try {
    console.log("Start Document Analysis");
    let analysisResults = await textract
      .startDocumentAnalysis(config)
      .promise();
    console.log("Doc analysis successful!", analysisResults);
    let textractResult = await textract
      .getDocumentAnalysis({ JobId: analysisResults["JobId"] })
      .promise();  
    console.log("End!", textractResult);
    return textractResult;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("There was an error during doc analysis...");
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  }
}
```

I worry about answering this way, because it doesn't seem to address the symptom described (two success logs), but even if there's another problem in the code, I think this is still a valid rewrite, form-wise.